# Logo Markers over 3D Maps View

Tags: google-maps

Trying to figure out if I can have a bunch of static JPG Markers over a 3D tilt view similar to:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/aerial-simple

I found a similar example here:

http://www.zingjet.com/maptest.html

But, we want to have it defaulted to only the 3D view and have many JPG icons over it. Anyone with a similar experience?

Comment: You can't have only 3D view, it's only available for particular areas

Answer (score -1):

Man, did you tried to do with JS or CSS ?

You can create a class and set your div with image:

```
.image{
display: block;
 background: transparent url("A/B") no-repeat scroll 95% 48%;
}
```